# Библиотека Glide для Android

Tags: java, android

Загружаю картинки в gridview по url. Картинки начинают загружаться только при появлении элемента списка на экране. Как их можно подгрузить (допустим штук 7) до того, как они появляются на экране, чтобы пользователь не смотрел по несколько секунд на progressbar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы, видимо, стартуете загрузку в методе отрисовки элемента `gridView` в его адаптере (что-то типа `getView`), оттого и получаете такое поведение.

Чтобы начать загрузку раньше можно начать загрузку в конструкторе адаптера. Далее всё зависит от особенностей библиотеки. Если она поддерживает вытаскивание картинок из кэша как [UIL](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader), то проблем не будет. Если нет, придётся повозиться со своей имплементацией.